# Promise is not working in azure function app javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, azure-function-async

I have simple demo to understand Promise concept but it is not working as expected,
see my code which i have tried.

```
module.exports = async function (context, iotHubMessage) {

    context.log('START');
    var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve('foo');
        }, 1000);

    });

    context.log(promise1);

    promise1.then(function (resolve) {
         context.log(resolve);
        // expected output: "foo"
    });

};
```

and I am geting this output

```
2019-01-24T12:58:38.695 [Information] START
2019-01-24T12:58:38.695 [Information] Promise { <pending> }
2019-01-24T12:58:38.696 [Information] Executed
```

why am not getting `foo` at output log please help me thanks!

Comment: That code will definitely eventually run that `console.log(resolve)` with `'foo'` **if** the process is still running a second later. Did you look later in the output?

Comment: Note that there's no reason to mark that function `async`. It doesn't ever use `await`.

Comment: can you post the code of context.log function?

Comment: yes @T.J.Crowder i waited before copy log

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Azure is killing your process after the function has returned. Because it didn't return a promise (or rather, didn't return a promise that did wait for your timeout), it did not wait for the promise callback to run.

You can use

```
module.exports = function(context, iotHubMessage) {
//               ^^^^^^^^ no async necessary here
    context.log('START');
    var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });
    context.log(promise1);
    var promise2 = promise1.then(function() {
        context.log("promise fulfilled");
    });
    return promise2;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

or with `async`/`await` syntax:

```
module.exports = async function(context, iotHubMessage) {
    context.log('START');
    var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });
    context.log(promise1);
    await promise1;
//  ^^^^^
    context.log("promise fulfilled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of `promise1.then(...)` try:

```
module.exports = async function (context, iotHubMessage) {

    context.log('START');
    var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve('foo');
        }, 1000);

    });

    context.log(promise1);

    // Use await instead of promise.then(...)

    let resolve = await promise1;
    context.log(resolve);

};
```