# Why is Axios not returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, azure-functions

I have the following code but I get no console output. It seems like no matter what I do it doesn't enter the `then()` or `catch()`.

```
axios
  .post(url, {test: "0"})
  .then(console.log)       
  .catch(console.error);
```

Interestingly enough the request gets posted and is received on the other end. I can also verify by mocking with postman that the endpoint is responding correctly. Where could this fail?

**EDIT**: It is getting even weirder: I tried the following and it instantly prints the promise:

```
console.log(await axios.post(url, {test: "0"}));
```

Unfortunately I am forced to use Node v8.11.1 - could this be the issue?

**EDIT 2**: `.then(console.log)` is just another way of writing `.then(response => console.log(response))` but just to be sure I went to the [official doc](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md) and used the recommend way as well:

```
axios
  .post(url, {test: "0"})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

The problem persists.

Comment: `.then((response) => console.log(response))` over here is failing and do the same thing with the catch too.

Comment: @NicolaeMaties There is no difference.

Comment: @NicolaeMaties Why? AFAIK a direct invocation is totally legal here

Comment: Try the code [here](https://github.com/axios/axios), under the heading "Performing a POST Request."

Comment: Isn't the console Object overwritten by something? You could try putting debugger statements in callbacks provided to then and catch to see if any of them are invoked (`.then(response => {debugger;})`). Also, you can check out the return value of the post function directly, to see if it is a Promise or not

Comment: Just for the records, have you checked if it's the CORS problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's basically the same but I tried it out just in case and same behavior

Comment: @bgazsi I tried that but it doesn't even seem to enter the `then()` so the bugger isn't started

Comment: @leonheess If the `url` in your request is different from where you are sending the request (e.g. website is on localhost and api is hosted somewhere) you have to enable the [Cross-origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) by adding the header to your API `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "your domain"`

Comment: @Mirakurun Good idea but I set CORS to * and it didn't change anything :/

Comment: Are you sure the url is not null or invalid?

Comment: @VassilisPallas Quoting my own question: *Interestingly enough the request gets posted and is received on the other end.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a problem of Axios at all. Azure killed my process immediately after the POST and didn't wait for the Promise to resolve. In case someone has a similar problem, see [Promise is not working in azure function app javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347873/promise-is-not-working-in-azure-function-app-javascript)